# Jackson: deserializing a generic type that contains a list

Tags: java, json, jackson

The entity that I am looking to deserialize from JSON is as follows:

```
public class TypedMemberDTO<T> {

        private List<T> details;
        private String type;

        // Getters and setters
    }
```

I know that `T` may only be one of two actual classes depending on the `type` attribute's value.

I've seen examples on how to deserialize lists using `objectMapper.readValue(json, objectMapper.getTypeFactory().collectionType(ArrayList.class, MyClass.class));`

However, I haven't seen any examples on how to achieve what I'm looking to do above.

Can someone please point me in the right direction on deserializing my class?

Ideally I want to avoid any annotation based approach if that is possible

Comment: I don't think this is possible (due to the type erasure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @fge suggested in his comment, you can use a custom deserializer to achieve this.

Assuming that `type` contains the fully qualified class name of the elements of the list, the following deserializer will do the job:

```
public class TypedMemberDTODeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<TypedMemberDTO<?>> {

    @Override
    public TypedMemberDTO<?> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException {
        try {
            JsonNode rootNode = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
            String type = rootNode.get("type").asText();
            JavaType parametricListType = ctxt.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(
                    List.class, Class.forName(type));
            JsonNode detailsNode = rootNode.get("details");
            List<?> detailsList = new ObjectMapper().readValue(detailsNode.toString(), parametricListType);
            return new TypedMemberDTO(detailsList, type); // unchecked
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }

    }
}
```

The `ObjectMapper` needs to be informed about the deserializer:

```
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new SimpleModule().addDeserializer(TypedMemberDTO.class,
                new TypedMemberDTODeserializer()));
        TypedMemberDTO<?> typedMemberDTO = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, TypedMemberDTO.class);
```

I don't know the performance of this solution (it's using an embedded `ObjectMapper` in the deserializer), you may have to check that. You can read more about custom deserializers [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers).